# MonacaのTODO管理アプリで写真や文字を保持する方法

Tags: javascript, monaca

プログラム初心者です。
MonacaのサンプルにあるTODO管理アプリで、追加した写真や文字が一度閉じるとリセットされ消えます。閉じた後再度開いても残っているようにしたいのですが、プログラムや方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして。MonacaのTODO管理アプリとのことですが、以下のURLにあるもので間違いないでしょうか？

https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/samples/todo/

ウェブサイトを一度閉じるとすべてリセットされてしまうというのは、入力されたデータが保存（永続化）されていないためです。MonacaはHTMLとJavaScriptでアプリを開発するためのフレームワークですので、JavaScriptを使ってデータの保存をしたければ、[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)などを使って、データの永続化をしてみるのをおすすめします。LocalStorageを使うことで、データの保存と読み出しを行うことができるようになるので、TODOを追加する際に保存、アプリを開く際に読み込みを行うことで、入力したデータを残すことができます。

また、こちらのQiitaの記事なども参考になります
https://qiita.com/masamitsu-konya/items/c69515604570150d3ab9

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。URLのもので間違いないです。LocalStorageの使い方が良く分からないのですが、サンプルプログラムに新たなプログラムを追加するだけでいいのでしょうか？どこにどのようなプログラムを入れるか（可能ならばプログラムそのもの）を教えていただけると助かります。ちなみにウェブサイトではなくMonacaデバッカーで実装しています。